# In TFS, which branch should I start adding my new project to?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

We have recently started using TFS. Here is our branching structure:

[image]

We created Main branch first. Then branched out DEV and Stage out of it.

Then branched out Prod out of Stage.

Now the question is if I have to start with a brand new project, I would add it to the DEV branch. When I am done with development, I merge it into Main branch then stage and then prod when ready to go live.

Questions:

- Is it the right process? If yes...Great :)
- OR should I create an empty project in Main and then merge into Dev. Then start my actual coding there?
- If I should start with Main, Why? and What do I lose by starting with Dev.

Note: I am considering Forward merge only and not production fixes or anything.

Comment: Thats the right process, you have to add it to Development branch and then as the testing progresses you will merge it to Main/Stage/Prod.

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branching-and-merging+tfs

Comment: Many projects are moving away from the branch-per-environment model, instead relying on short-lived feature branches that are frequently merged back to trunk, but are locked away behind feature flags until they're vetted and ready for production. This has some big advantages, but also has some difficulties and downsides.

Comment: After reading around and from the inputs, I don't see any added value of starting from Main in our case.